# Eloquent Relationship Between Two Unions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have four models. TableFoo and TableFooArchive share a common schema (items for TableFoo are periodically moved to TableFooArchive). I also have TableBar and TableBarArchive. TableFoo may or may not have one related row in TableBar or TableBarArchive. TableFooArchive may or may not have one related row in TableBarArchive.

I'd like to be able, using Eloquent, to union TableFoo and TableFooArchive then eager load the union of TableBar and TableBarArchive. If I only had TableFoo and TableBar, I could just set up a hasOne on the model and be done. How can I achieve the same with all four tables?

My start is to have a repository with the following:

```
public function getData($id)
{
    $a = TableFoo::selectRaw('
        columnA,
        columnB as column_b_abc,
        columnB as colum_b_def,
        created_at
    ')
    ->whereRaw("
        id = $id,
        and so forth...
    ");

    $b = TableFooArchive::selectRaw('
        columnA,
        columnB as column_b_abc,
        columnB as colum_b_def,
        created_at
    ')
    ->whereRaw("
        id = $id,
        and so forth...
    ")
    ->unionAll($a)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();

    return $b;
}
```

My guess is that it's possible to define a method on each model that returns TableBarTableBarArchive. I'm just not sure how I would do that nor how I would pull it through on the above using ->with('unionedResults'). FWIW, I can't change the table structure to use two instead of four.

I feel like there's probably an obvious and simple solution that just isn't occurring to me at the moment. Any help or insight would be appreciated!

UPDATE:
What I was looking for was to lazy load the relationship. The example above achieves this provided you have the correct methods defined on the related models.

It would still be interesting to see an example of eager loading the whole thing.

Comment: Off-topic: Can I ask why you've decided to use these `Archive` tables as opposed to a column called `achive` with a `0/1` flag? I think that you could more easily manage your data if you weren't moving them to new tables. Infact, you can set a `scope` on your model to deal with the `archive`. You can also set a global scope to ignore archives and apply/un-apply where you feel the need so you aren't restricted in you data. This way, you could truly take advantage of Eloquent and `hasOne` without restrictions.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy It wasn't my decision so I'm stuck with it until we can get away from the current structure. The Foo tables can't even be tied back to customers without doing full text search in three different fields. As such, keeping the number of records in the main table was necessary to have any hope of returning the most popular queries in a reasonable time frame. And by reasonable, we're talking 10-15 seconds. Fwiw, these are tables written by Asterisk.

Comment: Is it possible to create a pivot table that makes these relationships for you?